# How to make a text slideshow using CSS/HTML/JAVA

Tags: html, css, image, slideshow

So, I wanna make text slideshow using CSS and HTML for my website. (I can use Java too) I want a specific kind....like the one used for this website (http://kickammender.com/) under its logo.

If anyone can figure out what code to write for this, it would be great.

Comment: That effect in the example site that you provided uses javascript. I dont think it is possible with pure CSS and HTML

Comment: You can start here - http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) for this.

Here's an running example with just CSS and HTML.

```css
.slider {
  height: 18px;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.slider div, .slider div p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider div {
  animation: slide 10s 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% { margin-top: 0; }
  25% { margin-top: -18px; }
  50% { margin-top: -36px; }
  75% { margin-top: -54px; }
  100% { margin-top: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
    <p>
      Duis laoreet risus nunc, id iaculis velit finibus non.
    </p>
    <p>
      Pellentesque dictum nisi et tincidunt euismod.
    </p>
    <p>
      Proin in interdum enim, in ultricies massa.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much! I was being too lazy to make the whole code myself :) After playing around with the code, I made it to fit in my website perfectly! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use animation via keyframes
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp

or via SVG, which is a standard part of HTML5
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-animation.html

Tip for disappearing text: small div with no overflow, div with texts inside, animation has to change its top.